# Alternative to deprecated pipeP in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I currently have something like this implementation using Ramda's [pipeP](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeP):

```
const fetchAmount = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({value: 5}, 1000)))

const getTotal = pipeP(
  fetchAmount,
  prop('value'),
  add(2)
)

await getTotal() //=> 7
```

And I've seen that it's deprecated and the only solution I found is adding `then`, like:

```
const fetchAmount = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve({value: 5}, 1000)))

const getTotal = pipeP(
  fetchAmount,
  then(prop('value')),
  then(add(2))
)

await getTotal() //=> 7
```

Is this the way to go? I guess there might be important reasons to deprecate `pipeP` because it was really easy to use when combining promises with pure functions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, this was deprecated in [v0.26.0](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/2702).

Ramda added [`pipeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pipeWith) and [`composeWith`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#composeWith), which covered a wider spectrum.

`pipeP (f1, f2, ..., fn)` can be written as `pipeWith (then) ([f1, f2, ..., fn])`.

If you want the exact same signature, you can write something like this:

```js
const pipePromises = unapply (pipeWith (then))

pipePromises (
  (n) => Promise .resolve (n + 1),
  (n) => Promise .resolve (n * n),
  (n) => Promise .resolve (n - 3)
) 
(4) 
.then (console .log)  //~> 22
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.js"></script>
<script>const {unapply, pipeWith, then} = R              </script>
```

Comment: Can we mix async and sync functions in the composition?