# Consecutive promises, declarative way. How to?

Tags: typescript, ramda.js

I have this code (it's formatted by `prettier` btw):

```
    const gameInfoProcessed: ProcessedGameInfo = await checkMissingRequiredKeys(
      gameInfoInitial
    ).then((i) =>
      checkUnsupportedKeys(i).then((i) => checkReplayFileExists(i))
    );
```

It works exactly as I want, but it looks a bit too weird, and I wanna some more declarative, clear way.

One idea I had is to use Ramda's pipe:

```
    const gameInfoProcessed: ProcessedGameInfo = await R.pipe(
      checkMissingRequiredKeys,
      checkUnsupportedKeys,
      checkReplayFileExists,
    )(gameInfoInitial);
```

Which is almost perfect, except it doesn't work: all my functions are async, and it turns out, unlike real life, in programming promises can't be put into a pipe. There's `pipeP` though, a promise version of pipe, which is presumably what I need, but they deprecated it in v0.26.0, and in newer versions I don't see this function available (and I don't want to use deprecated shit, - there should be a reason why it's deprecated???).

I know it's possible to do with Promise.all too:

```
    const gameInfoProcessed: ProcessedGameInfo = R.mergeAll(
      (await Promise.all(
        [
          checkMissingRequiredKeys(gameInfoInitial),
          checkUnsupportedKeys(gameInfoInitial),
          checkReplayFileExists(gameInfoInitial),
        ],
      )),
    );
```

It has a bit more clutter but at least I may clearly see my functions, which is kinda what I want... But it's not equivalent to my initial code for few different reasons, one of which is `mergeAll`, - because I get list or individual results, and mergeAll doesn't merge *deeply*, so I lose some information here.

Any idea how to make these consecutive promises look better, having some clear short code?

Comment: You may be interested in discussions at https://github.com/ramda/ramda/pull/1869

Comment: @snak uhm, they decided it's "contentious", and closed this PR. It seems they deprecated it later anyway though D: I found an alternative though, - details in my own answer

Comment: Ramda did go through with removing direct Promise support, ending up with an `andThen` function (`then` caused problems.)  And, as your answer shows, `pipeWith` and `composeWith` work well with `andThen` to make a replacement for the deprecated `pipeP`/`composeP`.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59229998/3720305), I ended up with this:

```
    const gameInfoProcessed: ProcessedGameInfo = await R.pipeWith(R.andThen)([
      checkMissingRequiredKeys,
      checkUnsupportedKeys,
      checkReplayFileExists,
    ])(gameInfoInitial);
```

It seems to be equivalent to the initial code, and it's declarative, - I see all the functions clearly ;)